# An exercise on image measure

Tags: probability, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Given:

1. $((0,1), \mathbb B((0,1)), \lambda)$ a measure space, where $\lambda$ is Lebesgue measure;
2. $\mu$ be a probability measure on $(\mathbb R, \mathbb B(\mathbb R))$
3. $F(t) = \mu((-\infty,t]), t \in \mathbb R$
4. $f: (0,1) \to \mathbb R$ defined by $f(x) = \inf \{t:F(t) \geq x \}$.

Show that: $\mu = f_*\lambda$, which means $\forall I \in \mathbb B (\mathbb R), \mu(I)=\lambda(f^{-1}(I))$.

$(4)$ means: 
$$t \geq f(x) \Leftrightarrow F(t) \geq x, \forall t \in \mathbb R, \forall x \in (0,1)$$
Or 
$$x \in f^{-1}((-\infty,t]) \Leftrightarrow F(t) \geq x, \forall t \in \mathbb R, \forall x \in (0,1)$$

What should I do next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$f^{-1}\left(\left(-\infty,t\right]\right)=\left\{ x\in\left(0,1\right)\mid F\left(t\right)\geq x\right\} =\left(0,F\left(t\right)\right]$$

and consequently:$$f_{*}\lambda\left(\left(-\infty,t\right]\right)=\lambda\left(f^{-1}\left(\left(-\infty,t\right]\right)\right)=\lambda((0,F(t)])=F\left(t\right)$$

So $\mu$ and $f_{*}\lambda$ are probability measures that have equal CDF's.

Then you are allowed to conclude that $\mu=f_{*}\lambda$.

Comment: what is the role of probability measure here?

Comment: Actually it does not play a role of importance. Coincidentally there two measures are involved that both can be classified as probability measure. Essential is that $\nu_1(-\infty,t]=\nu_2(-\infty,t]<\infty$ for each $t\in\mathbb R$ is enough to conclude that $\nu_1=\nu_2$. I added the tag probability to draw more attention for the question.